# convert from localdate to string in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, format, localdate

I want to convert a localdate "StartDate" to string so I can concatenate without a problem but the methode format doesn't work
this is my service where the problem is:

```
    List<DatesRequest> datesRequests = PaidRequest.getDatesRequest();
    String StartDate = datesRequests.stream().map(DatesRequest::getStartDate).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            CollaboratorDTO validator = OrganizationalUintService.findValidator(collaboratorTransformer.entityTranferToDTO(PaidRequest.getCollaborator()));
        EmailService.sendSimpleMessage(validator.getEmail(),
                "EverHoliday",
                " Bonjour "+validator.getFirstname()+" "+validator.getLastname()+","
                + " \n "+ PaidRequest.getCollaborator().getLastname()+" " +PaidRequest.getCollaborator().getFirstname()+
                " a ajouté une demande de congé du  "+StartDate+ " en attente de votre approbation "
                + " \n Cordialement.");
```

`String StartDate = datesRequests.stream().map(DatesRequest::getStartDate).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));` the error that show up is "Cannot resolve method 'format' in 'Stream'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message describes the issue. Method .format is absent at Stream interface. see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html
I think that you want to transform the object to string and concatenate it. So:

```
String StartDate = datesRequests.stream().map(DatesRequest::getStartDate).map(date -> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy").format(date)).collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `startDate` is `LocalDateTime` type, you can format it like this:

```
List<String> collect = datesRequests.stream().map(DatesRequest::getStartDate).stream().map(d -> {
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"); // Usually we new the formatter outside of the stream 
        return d.format(dateTimeFormatter);
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please note that your input is a list, so you need to accumulate the elements.